# How to prevent scripts from downloading data from another directory?

Tags: javascript, json, content-security-policy, cross-origin-read-blocking, cross-origin-embedder-policy

There is a script at https://example.com/private/data.json that return JSONs **only to logged** users
(server return JSON ony if you have the right entry in your session)

```
{
    "something":"private"
}
```

At https://example.com/private/script.js is this simple script that downloads data.json and prints it in the console

```
fetch("https://example.com/private/data.json", {method: "GET"})
 .then(response => console.log('fetch', response.text()) )
 .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Suppose someone copies the same script to multiple locations. For example:

- https://example.com/script.js
- https://example.com/anything/script.js
- https://example.com/anything/else/script.js

## My questions

1. I want to prevent downloading data.json from other scripts than https://example.com/private/script.js **even if you are logged-in**
2. What header, Content-Security-Policy, content-policy (or anything else) should the server return so that the browser can list this JSON only from the script running at https://example.com/private/script.js but could not list it in script https://example.com/script.js or https://example.com/anything/script.js?

Comment: You could use the CSP `connect-src` directive: `Content-Security-Policy: connect-src 'self' https://example.com/script.js`. But if the document is causing requests to be initiated to any other origins, you’d then need to have host-source expressions for all of them in your `connect-src` value — that is, the `connect-src` value is an allow list that causes requests to any other origins to be denied by default unless you add host-source expressions to explicitly allow them.

Comment: is there any way, how to reny only one URL, or example.com/private/* mask, without denying anything else?

Comment: No, in CSP there’s no way to deny only one source while allowing others. The values of CSP directives are essentially allow lists, not deny lists. When a particular directive is specified, the behavior it controls basically starts out as “deny all’ — that is, it has the effect of denying everything. Then anything you don’t want to deny, you need to explicitly allow — by adding a specific source expression that will allow it.